# How to pop-up info window on google map dynamically using gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, gmaps4rails

I am using rails 3.2.13 and gmaps4rails(1.5.6) with mongoid.

There are some listings in the left side on the page and on right side there is a google map with all listing locations.

My Requirement : 
when user select any listing in the HTML view need to pop up the info window of that listing on google map.

For eg : https://maps.google.pl/maps?hl=pl&q=pharmacy&ie=UTF-8.

Comment: i am facing same problem.